# Verifying a signed XML with public key in java

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, public-key, verify

Hey guys I have a signed a XML with the private key and now I want to verify with public key that it was the same private key used to sign the XML.

My verify() function is below

```
       public boolean verify(String signedXml) {

    boolean verificationResult = false;

    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        Document signedDocument = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(signedXml)));

        NodeList nl = signedDocument.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "Signature");
        if (nl.getLength() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot find Signature element");
        }

        XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

        DOMValidateContext valContext = new DOMValidateContext(getCertificateFromFile(publicKeyFile).getPublicKey(), nl.item(0));
        XMLSignature signature = fac.unmarshalXMLSignature(valContext);

        verificationResult = signature.validate(valContext);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while verifying digital siganature" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return verificationResult;
}
```

And the getCertificateFromFile() is

```
       public X509Certificate getCertificateFromFile(String certificateFile) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", "BC");
        fis = new FileInputStream(certificateFile);
        return (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(fis);
    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
    }

}
```

when I verify my Signed XML with public key (.cer ) it returns always true no matter how many changed I made in signed XML, I even used different private key and it still giving true !
Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably didn't sign the data you've intended to sign. If you sign a specific node of the XML then you'd only get a failed verification when you change that specific node. Show the XML and the signing code here so we can check such facts. Hmm, missed this one as it wasn't tagged with crypto.

Comment: its working now, I just found out that it gives cache result for multiple runs. Thanks for suggestions